# Using temporary extended table to make a sum

Tags: sql, postgresql

From a given table I want to be able to sum values having the same number (should be easy, right?)

**Problem**: A given value can be assigned from 2 to n consecutive numbers.
For some reasons this information is stored in a single row describing the value, the starting number and the ending number as below.

**TABLE A**

```
 id | starting_number | ending_number | value
----+-----------------+---------------+-------
  1                 2                5      8
  2                 0                3      5
  3                 4                6      6
  4                 7                8     10
```

For instance the first row means: 
value '8' is assigned to numbers: 2, 3 and 4 (5 is excluded)

So, I would like the following intermediairy result table

**TABLE B**

```
 id | number | value
----+--------+-------
  1        2       8
  1        3       8
  1        4       8
  2        0       5
  2        1       5
  2        2       5
  3        4       6
  3        5       6
  4        7      10
```

So I can sum 'value' for elements having identical 'number'

```
SELECT number, sum(value)
FROM B
GROUP BY number
```

**TABLE C**

```
 number | sum(value)
--------+------------
      2           13
      3            8
      4           14
      0            5
      1            5
      5            6
      7           10
```

I don't know how to do this and didn't find any answer on the web (maybe not looking with appropriate key words...)
Any idea?

Comment: Reading the documentation helps a lot... http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtableas.html

Comment: If only I had months (years) in front of me, be sure I would read it fully. Just trying not to waste days on a simple problem that can be obvious to some experts. I think this is the philosophy of SO, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want with `generate_series()`.  So, TableB is basically:

```
select id, generate_series(starting_number, ending_number - 1, 1) as n, value
from tableA;
```

Your aggregation is then:

```
select n, sum(value)
from (select id, generate_series(starting_number, ending_number - 1, 1) as n, value
      from tableA
     ) a
group by n;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for. I thought there could be a simpler solution to this (no nested queries). But it does the job perfectly and doesn't seem to consume too much CPU.